# Get performance counters from VMWare vSphere using VIX?

Tags: com, vmware, vix

I can use VMWare PowerCLI to get CPU usage with command line like "get-stat -entity $vm -realtime -maxsample $n -stat cpu.usage.average".

As far as I know PowerCLI uses VMWare VIX API to communicate with vSphere server.

But I can't find VIX API method which allows me to get such performance counter.

Am I wrong? Or should I use full VMWare SDK instead of VIX to get performance data? Thank you.